# Location of passenger log files in my ec2 instance (elastic beanstalk + rails)

Tags: logging, amazon-web-services, passenger, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy a Rails application on Elastic Beanstalk. I'd like to be able to look at my web server log files (which should be Passenger) but I don't know where to find them in my ec2 instance. I was able to SSH into the instance, but I had no luck finding the files.

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On Elastic Beanstalk ruby container you can find your application logs (passenger.log, production.log) at /var/app/support/logs/.

The files /var/log/eb-tools.log and /var/log/cfn-init.log are also useful for debugging deployment issues.

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to update this info. I am using Rails 4.1, and the log files were not in these locations. Instead, they were in /var/app/containerfiles/logs